# Need to display content only during business hours

Tags: php, date, time, timezone

I need to display content between 9am and 6pm central time. I've tried various ways to do this with php, but the result are never accurate. One example I tried is:

```
<?
$openTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' 09:00:00');
$closeTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' 18:00:00');
$currTime = strtotime('now');

if (($openTime <= $currTime) && ($currTime <= $closeTime)) { ?>
```

But that never even came close to being accurate with our server's time. Our server is supposedly in Central US timezone, but again, the code above doesn't work.

So is there a way where hours can be specified ALONG with a specified timezone to get this working correctly? Since the above code doesn't work accurately it looks like the php is using a different timezone than our server's. All I want is for content to show between 9am and 6pm central time. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: If you use the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php), you can set timezones at runtime, independent of server configuration.

Comment: That sounds like what I need. Also my apologies but I'm a complete novice with php. How would I apply that class in the above code?

Comment: see @Fabricator 's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Datetime('now', timezone)` to get the current time

```
$curdate = new Datetime('now', new Datetimezone('America/Chicago'));
```

Use `setTime` to set hour and minute

```
$openTime = clone $curdate;
$openTime->setTime(9,0);

$endTime = clone $curdate;
$endTime->setTime(18,0);
```

Comment: +1. This is indeed the correct way to go. I think it'd be better to mention that DateTime objects are comparable. It may not be obvious for someone who is new to using DateTime objects :)

Answer (score 0):

Set your timezone using:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Your time zone')
```

Available timezones here : [Acceptable timezones](http://www.php.net//manual/en/timezones.php)